# WPF Path or Polygon scale

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to have a figure like a sealed envelope - Grid and four adjacent trapezoids inside on each Grid's side
Leaving some empty space in the middle(in a shape of a rectangle).
How can I make those trapezoids scale with the Grid, not using any code or ViewBox?

Comment: Why is a ViewBox not suitable?

Comment: Because it wont give correct positioning of trapezoids - in some cases it will overlap

Comment: Maybe if you show us your ViewBox code we can help fix that. If you want to scale to the containing control then it is probably going to be the best solution.

Comment: Posted answer to my question below ... task is to have drag/drop areas on a grid - top side. left, right, bottom - so I mustn't have any elements overlapping. New layout, like in my answer, helps

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing the layout helped - made a 3*3 grid, and used elements like so:

```
<Polygon Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Points="0,0 1,1 1,0 0,0" Fill="Gray" Stretch="Fill"/>
<Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Gray"/>
<Polygon Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Points="0,0 0,1 1,0 0,0" Fill="Gray" Stretch="Fill"/>
```